# imagemagick evaluate image smoothness

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick

I am processing lot of images of the same size with imagemagick. In any image I have four possible places (left up, left down, right up, right down) where the image describing text could be put in. From the four envisages areas I will find that one, which is at most "smooth", so that the text put over it will be legible (not disturbed by underlying image part).

To find the desired candidate I was trying to use the imagemagick's command *identify* with the parameter standard-deviation, kurtosis, entropy and skewness, but none of them led to optimal solution. Is there any way to ask imagemagick to evaluate the smoothnes of the given rectangular
areas?

Comment: Please click [edit] and add a representative image, along with your code and show which quadrant it selected and say which quadrant you feel it should have selected and why.

Comment: Do you know how large the text area will be?  Or are you talking about one of the 4 quadrants of the image --- top-left, top-right, bottom-right, bottom left? If the latter, crop the image into its 4 quadrants. Then for each quadrant, get the standard-deviation. The one with the lowest standard deviation will be the   smoothest.

Comment: the second thing is my case (4 quadrants). I am using the following statement:  identify -channel %1 -format "%1 %%[standard-deviation]" %home%%2.jpg. I get 3 values for each channel (R, G, B). Shall I use the sum, average, minimum or maximum of those values?

Comment: User supplies jpg images and an explaining text for each image. My app should place the text over the image. The text should be good legible but also the image should be "disfigured" as less as possible by the text.
The text should be positioned in one of four rectangular areas of the image. The offsets to image margin and area size depends on image size, text size und text length.
I compute the positions of the four areas and then I select the most "smooth" of them by means of imagemagick (using standar-deviation of each area). To the selected area I put down the text .

Comment: To fulfill the above mentioned conditions of legibility and not to damage the image I need to know how "smooth" the
area is, to decide if the label background may be left transparent or it needed to be used with a non transparent  color (mean color of the selected rectangular area). The non transparent text is much less invasive to the image, than the narrower one. To take the decision (transparent or not), the standard-deviation is not helpfull.

Comment: For the longer text (wider rectangular area) the value of the standar-deviation tends to be lower then it is for the shorter texts. I was trying to inspect standard-deviations of separate R,G,B color chanels, I was experimenting with other image characteristics furnished by imagemagick (entropy, skewness, kurtosis) and of kombinations of them. I found no helpfull solution.
I imagine, that there must be other programmers wich have had to cope with the same problem. Please help me!

Comment: If you would like help, we’d need to see some reprresentative imagesand texts and corresponding expected layouts.

Answer (score 1):

Using this image:

[image]

Photo by [Marek Piwnicki](https://unsplash.com/@marekpiwnicki?utm_content=creditCopyText&utm_medium=referral&utm_source=unsplash) on [Unsplash](https://unsplash.com/photos/blue-and-white-smoke-illustration-eBoUd9Fdm8Y?utm_content=creditCopyText&utm_medium=referral&utm_source=unsplash)

You could try this to convert to greyscale and print the variance (actually standard deviation) of each quadrant:

```
magick image.jpg -colorspace gray -crop 50% -format "%[standard-deviation]\n" info:
10538.1   # top left
9875.02   # top right
1406.89   # bottom left
1237.25   # bottom right
```

As the variance (and standard deviation) measure how much variation there is between the pixels, the quadrant with the lowest standard deviation would be selected. That would suggest the bottom left or bottom right quadrant for your text on this particular image.

---

Another metric you could try on your images is *"entropy"*, that would be like this and suggest the same quadrant:

```
magick image.jpg -colorspace gray -crop 50% -format "%[entropy]\n" info:
0.565705
0.639645
0.469206
0.401134
```